# rbenv and Apple m1. Failed installing ruby 3.2, 2.7 and 2.6

Tags: ruby, rbenv, ruby-3

I can't install any ruby version with rbenv. I tried 2.6.10 2.7.7 or 3.2.0 .

This is the error I got when executing:

```
❯ rbenv install 3.2.0
To follow progress, use 'tail -f /var/folders/4v/kyv3nw1s7lq8s7lz7r6djvsr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20230125170342.85553.log' or pass --verbose
Downloading openssl-3.0.7.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/83049d042a260e696f62406ac5c08bf706fd84383f945cf21bd61e9ed95c396e
Installing openssl-3.0.7...
Installed openssl-3.0.7 to /Users/idanahal/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0

Downloading ruby-3.2.0.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/ruby-3.2.0.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.2.0...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
ruby-build: using gmp from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 13.1 using ruby-build 20221225)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/4v/kyv3nw1s7lq8s7lz7r6djvsr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20230125170342.85553.VSOgmw
Results logged to /var/folders/4v/kyv3nw1s7lq8s7lz7r6djvsr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20230125170342.85553.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ossl_x509ext.c
compiling ossl_x509name.c
compiling ossl_x509req.c
compiling ossl_x509revoked.c
compiling ossl_x509store.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
linking shared-object openssl.bundle
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

When installing with Homebrew it's working. I don't know what to do. Should rbenv even suppose to work with m1 computers?

I have MacOS 13.1

Comment: You'll probably need to look into the indicated log file. This doesn't seem to contain any actual errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the environment variable below solves the problem:

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-zlib-dir=$(brew --prefix zlib) --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1) --with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline) --with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml) --with-gdbm-dir=$(brew --prefix gdbm)"
```

before running `rbenv install` for all versions.

Note: The configuration `--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)` is needed only for versions  `2.6.*` and `2.7.*`. You can (and should) remove it if you are trying to install ruby `3.*.*`.

For 2.6 and 2.7 sometimes this environment variable also needed:

```
export RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

If all of the above didn't work, you can install ruby with Homebrew.
If you want to manage the Homebrew installed version from rbenv read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75245960/4752738).

Comment: Note that this address requires `brew`, which raises some privacy issues.

Answer (score 0):

As I have described in [this blog post](https://johnskinnerportfolio.com/blog/ruby_330_error.html) of mine, you need to specify the path to the version of OpenSSL that your version of Ruby requires:

Ruby 3.1 and newer, use:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)" rbenv install 3.1.0
```

Ruby 2.4 to 3.0, use:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" rbenv install 2.4.0
```

Ruby 2.3 and older, use

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1)" rbenv install 2.3.0
```

But there is an **important security consideration!** OpenSSL version 1 was *deprecated years ago*. This means that Ruby 2.3 and older haven't been getting OpenSSL security updates for a long time. OpenSSL version 1.1 also stopped getting security updates in late 2023, meaning that all Ruby before 3.1 is potentially insecure.

The above assumes you have installed OpenSSL via Homebrew. That's what the `$(brew ...)` part is about — it fills in the path where Homebrew installed OpenSSL. If you did not install it with Homebrew, you'll want to instead set `--with-openssl-dir` equal to whatever path OpenSSL was installed at.

*Note:* In the terminal output you posted, you'll see a message like `Results logged to /path/name/file.log`. It would be helpful to your question if you added errors from this file.