# How to manage ruby version installed without rbenv in rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I had problems installing ruby with rbenv so I installed it with Homebrew.
The problem is that I still want to manage this ruby version with rbenv.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you installed ruby 2.7 (brew does not let you choose patch version): `brew install ruby@2.7`.

We will call this version `2.7-brew` in rbenv but you can call it whatever you like (for example `2.7`). Just change all pathes in this answer from `2.7-brew` to `2.7` or to another name.

We want rbenv to manage this ruby version:

```
cd ~/.rbenv/versions
mkdir -p 2.7-brew/bin
```

We need to link our newly installed ruby version:
replace `<Installed Version>` with the version brew installed (probably 2.7.7 or a greater patch version)

If you don’t know the version or the installation directory run:

```
brew info ruby@2.7
```

[image]

Link this ruby version to the directory we have created:

- On Mac computers with apple silicon (M1).

  `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby@2.7/<Installed Version>/bin/ruby 2.7-brew/bin/ruby`
- On Mac computers with amd64 architecture (Intell).

  `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/<Installed Version>/bin/ruby 2.7-brew/bin/ruby`

Let rbenv know that we added a new ruby version:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Now, rbenv should be able to use this new ruby version.